# How to test authenticated POST request with Pytest in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, automated-tests, pytest

I want to test an authenticated post request on an API using Pytest. This is what I am doing so far:

```
 def test_auth_user_can_create(self, client):
      
    
    url = api_reverse('crud-simulation_api')

    data = {
        "project": "testproject",
        ....
    }

        response = client.post(url, json=data)
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

This doesn't work because it gives me back a 401 (Unauthorized) instead of a 200. That makes sense since the fixture is a client and not an admin client.

Yet if I pass in admin_client instead of client it gives me a Bad Request. The data that I send should be fine though.

I also tried to pass in the headers like so (since I use JWT authorization):

```
token = "bigassstringwhichismytoken"

headers = {
        "Authorization": "JWT " + token
    }
```

Finally I tried to log in before which gives me a 403 (Forbidden):

```
def test_auth_user_can_create_simulation_api(self, client, django_user_model):
     
    username = "Jack"
    password = "password"

    django_user_model.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
    client.login(username=username, password=password)

    url = api_reverse('crud-simulation_api')

    data = {
        "project": "testproject",
        ...
    }

    response = client.post(url, json=data)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

If someone could point me into the right direction that would be fantastic! Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hit the login url with username and password and get the token.
creade a header dictionary like `headers = {'Authorization': 'JWT <token>'}`

and use the header when using post.

```
client.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank you Sam for your help! I'm sorry but what do you mean with I can hit the login url with username and password and get the token? I went on and I tried with ```auth_response = client.post(url_auth, username=username, password=password)``` Is that what you meant? Do I have to create a user for that?

Comment: No, you need to parse the token returned from ```client.login()``` and use that as header parameter in ```client.post()``` requests.

Comment: Thank you again sam. I followed these steps but it still give me a 400 (Bad Request). I got the token using ```response = client.post(url_auth, data)
        token = response.data.get("token", 0)``` Then I passed the token to the headers, but still the 400. Any more ideas?

Comment: never mind, that was a problem with my data I sent.

Comment: `Authorization` won't be passed as header, but instead will be passed as a nested key inside a new header called `headers`. This solution is incorrect and wouldn't work with default impelemtation of authorization.

Answer (score 3):

To provide headers for `client.{request}` pass them individually as keyword agruments:

```
client.post(url, data, HTTP_FIRST_HEADER='...', HTTP_SECOND_HEADER='...')
```

Although you're unlikely to collide with any reserved parameter names in `post` call chain, better collect all headers you need in a dictionary:

```
headers = {
    'HTTP_FIRST_HEADER': '...',
    'HTTP_SECOND_HEADER': '...',
}
```

And pass them to request as arbitrary number of keyword arguments:

```
client.post(url, data, **headers)
```

In this case `**` arguments are treated as [extra information and are automatically added as headers](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c32d8f33d8e988a376e44997b8f3606d821f305e/django/test/client.py#L467).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing the pytest-django package. Based on its [docs](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#admin-client-django-test-client-logged-in-as-admin), the easiest answer would be just using the **admin_client** fixture. As admin_client has the type of *django.test.Client*, it can be used for both get and post requests.

```
def test_sth_with_auth(admin_client):
    response = admin_client.get('/private')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Also if you want to use a specific user, you can try sth like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_user(django_user_model):
    return django_user_model.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)

@pytest.fixture
def logged_in_client(client, my_user):
    return client.force_login(my_user)

def test_sth_with_auth(logged_in_client):
    response = logged_in_client.get('/private')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

[this part](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#id2) of the doc can be helpful to write your desired logged_in_client().

Answer (score 0):

Access Using Token:

Make a fixture to create a User:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def user_token():
    user= User.objects.create_user(username="salah", password="passtest")
    Token.objects.create(user=user)
    return user.auth_token.key
```

Now, send it in headers:

```
def test_example(client, user_token):
    response = client.get(
        /lists/,
        HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f"Token {user_token}",
    )
```

Use **HTTP_AUTHORIZATION** for access.